# Java MongoDB save multiple documents at once

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver, mongotemplate

I Have a list of updated objects/documents i need save all the objects in the list at once.

I saw save() in MongoTemplate but it can take single document at a time. 
Is there any way to save multiple documents at once or i need to call save in loop ?

Comment: have you tried `insertAll()`

Comment: @pvpkiran insertAll() is for new documents but i need to update if the document exists or insert if its doesn't exists

Answer (score 5):

You can use `insertAll` of `MongoTemplate` or `ReactiveMongoTemplate`, but you have to use it with caution. It does what it's name stands for - it inserts all documents. If you call `save` method then the `save` has optimistic locking, so it checks if you don't override the document that you shouldn't (if it has the `@Version` annotation). `insertAll` doesn't check for optimistic locking so you can use it as long as you really want to do an insert e.g. persist documents that aren't persisted yet or you don't care about overriding those documents and optimistic locking. If you care about optimistic locking then all you can do is to call `save` for each document which will generate a lot of I/O operations, but that's what it takes to make sure that you will update documents with matching version.
Also you have to remember that `insertAll` actually inserts new documents, meaning that you can't update document using this method, because you'll get duplicated key exception. Currently spring mongo lacks a feature that would allow to update all the documents (you can only 'insert' them, so save for the first time)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for all the help.

I was able to do it using Spring data MongoDB.
Spring data MongoDB's MongoRepository has many inbuilt methods.

org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository.saveAll(Iterable entites) 
is the one which i used to save multiple documents.

Comment: Note that the default implementation of `MongoRepository.saveAll()` is `SimpleMongoRepository.saveAll()`, which fires off a separate request for every single update.

Answer (score 1):

Using Spring you can easily store multiple documents at once.

The Interface is already available with method saveAll and details as under:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MongoRepository<T, ID> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID>, QueryByExampleExecutor<T> {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository#saveAll(java.lang.Iterable)
     */
    @Override
    <S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entites);
//...
}
```

Spring usage example:

```
@Component
public class Processor {

@Autowired
public Processor(Repository repository) {
    this.repository= repository;
}

public void save(Iterable<ProductEntity> entites) {
    List<ProductEntity> saved = repository.saveAll(entites);
    logger.info("Saved {} entities", saved.size());
}

}
```

your Repository interface:

```
//https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html
public interface Repository extends MongoRepository<ProductEntity, String> {   
}
```

Call save method with 'List' of Product entities

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do.

```
mongoTemplate.getCollection("your_collection_name").insert(List<Documents>)
```

You might want to check out [BulkWriteOperation](http://api.mongodb.com/java/2.12/com/mongodb/BulkWriteOperation.html) class as well.

Answer (score 0):

For Insert:

You should use the function [InsertMany](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/?com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#insertMany-java.util.List-) like:

```
List<Document> docList = new List<Document>();
docList.add(doc1); // assuming that doc1 and doc2 are defined
docList.add(doc2);
yourMongoDb.getCollection("your_collection").insertMany(docList);
```

For Upsert (what you need):

```
UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true) ;
yourCollectionOfDocuments.forEach( doc ->{ 
    Document filter = Filters.eq("_id", doc.get("id"));
    yourDb.getCollection("your_collection").updateOne(filter,update,option); 
})
```

Comment: This solution is for new documents but i need update existing documents

Comment: I see. Then what you need is upsert:


`UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true);

yourCollectionOfDocuments.forEach( doc ->{

 Document filter = Filters.eq("_id", doc.get("id"))
 yourDb.getCollection("your_collection").updateOne(filter,update,option)

});
`