# How to perform Bulk Operation in MongoDB (similar to jdbdTemplate.batchUpdate() in Spring)?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

`jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", List<Object[]>);`

Is there a similar way that I can do same insert using `MongoRepository` Interfaces in `Spring data` `mongodb` and `java` ?

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657055/spring-data-mongodb-and-bulk-update

Comment: is there a way to batch insert ? insert multiple records without any conditional updates. Just basic insert for a list of records. (say 100 records/objects in mongodb into a single Document)

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718892/java-mongodb-save-multiple-documents-at-once

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java MongoDB save multiple documents at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718892/java-mongodb-save-multiple-documents-at-once)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert multiple documents into the collection using one of the following methods. Assuming a `test` collection and a `Test.java` POJO representng a document:

**(i) Inserting and Deleting using the `MongoRepository`:**

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<Test, String> {
    void deleteByIdIn(List<ObjectId> ids);
}
```

// Run the `saveAll` repository method:

```
Test t1 = new Test("apple");
Test t2 = new Test("banana");
Test t3 = new Test("orange");
List<Test> ts = repository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(t1, t2, t3));
```

From the *Mongo Shell* lookup the newly inserted documents in the `test` collection:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e579153c4d0e55b6ad5f869"), "name" : "apple", "_class" : "com.example.demo.Test" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e579153c4d0e55b6ad5f86a"), "name" : "banana", "_class" : "com.example.demo.Test" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e579153c4d0e55b6ad5f86b"), "name" : "orange", "_class" : "com.example.demo.Test" }
```

// Perform Delete by ids:

```
ObjectId o1 = new ObjectId("5e579153c4d0e55b6ad5f869"); // apple
ObjectId o2 = new ObjectId("5e579153c4d0e55b6ad5f86b"); // orange
List<ObjectId> ids = Arrays.asList(o1, o2);
repository.deleteByIdIn(ids);
```

The objects with names "apple" and "orange" will be deleted. Also, note that the `Test.java` POJO class *must* have the `id` field defined to refer and delete by that field.

**(ii) Using `MongoTemplate`:**

```
MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "test");
BulkOperations bulkOps = mongoOps.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, Test.class);

Test t1 = new Test("orange");
Test t2 = new Test("grape");
bulkOps.insert(Arrays.asList(t1, t2));
BulkWriteResult r = bulkOps.execute();
```

**(iii) The POJO `Test` Class:**

```
public class Test {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    public Test(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! repository.save() is working fine for above requirement.
How can i delete a list of items using a list of ids using custom query or in built methods ?
List<String> idList;
the list of items associated with above list of ids (idList) should be deleted?

Comment: I added the `deleteByIdIn(List<ObjectId> ids)` to the _repository_ object. Note the POJO class must define the `id` field for this functionality. See the _updated_ code.